# Databricks autocomplete symbol meaning

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-databricks

This might be a strange question but is there any documentation on databricks symbol representation that comes up with autocomplete box ?

[image: databricks autocomplete]

It would be really helpful if someone can provide me insights on what these symbol means. Thanks a lot in advance.